# Inserting data into psql database with high performance

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Assume, I have a Python program, and I have an `Offer` object `Offer(title='title1', category='cat1', regions=['reg1'])`.
I want to add this `Offer` into psql db, with minimal number of queries (performance). Inserts of **new** regions and categories are rare (number of regions and categories is limited (and are unique), but number of offers is unlimited).
Basically `Regions` and `Categories` can be inserted by query:

```
INSERT INTO Categories(name)
SELECT 'cat1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM Categories WHERE name = 'cat1'
    )
RETURNING id;
```

, but I need to execute another query to get id of region/category (when region/category already exists). I need this id to execute query inserting data to `Offers` table:

```
INSERT INTO Offers(title, category)
SELECT 'title1', (SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM Offers WHERE title = 'title1' AND category = (SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1')
    );
```

Currently my code looks like:

```
INSERT INTO Categories(name)
SELECT 'cat1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM Categories WHERE name = 'cat1'
    );

INSERT INTO Regions(name)
SELECT 'reg1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1'
    );

INSERT INTO Offers(title, category)
SELECT 'title1', (SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM Offers WHERE title = 'title1' AND category = (SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1')
    );

INSERT INTO OfferRegions(offer, region)
SELECT (SELECT id FROM Offers WHERE title = 'title1'), (SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM OfferRegions WHERE offer = (SELECT id FROM Offers WHERE title = 'title1') AND region = (SELECT id FROM Regions WHERE name = 'reg1')
    );
```

I don't know how to do it robust and efficient (without unnecessary SELECTs). I work with Python/psycopg2.

---

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Regions
(
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Categories
(
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Offers
(
    id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title    TEXT,
    category SERIAL REFERENCES Categories (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OfferRegions
(
    offer  SERIAL REFERENCES Offers (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    region SERIAL REFERENCES Regions (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (offer, region)
);
```

Comment: Your objective is unclear. Can you explain more in details the way you want to insert new rows in the offers table and which query you need for that ?

Comment: I edited my original question. I just want to improve my current solution.

Comment: If you add constraints to your database, disallowing references to records that don't exist, all you need to do is insert a new records and catch the error if it turns out that it does refer to a non-existent record. That way, any additional queries to enter the records referred to only get run when needed, but in most cases the insertion will work quickly. Of course, adding foreign key constraints to your database does come with a general performance penalty when inserting, updating and deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

For that, you need a unique constraint on the column that identifies the object.

That allows you to retrieve the generated `id`, for example:

```
INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('cat1')
ON CONFLICT ON (name) DO NOTHING
RETURNING id;
```

Dependent tables could be filled like this, using a variable `cat_id` that was set with the result from the above query:

```
INSERT INTO offers (category, title)
SELECT CASE WHEN cat_id IS NULL
            THEN (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name = 'cat1')
            ELSE cat_id
       END,
       /* similar for "title */
```

There is of course a race condition: someone could delete the `categories` row before your second `INSERT`. But perhaps that is good enough.

Comment: Thanks. This way I can get rid of unnecessary `WHERE NOT EXISTS` SELECTs while inserting `Region` or `Category`. But what about SELECTs while inserting `Offer` and especially `OfferRegions`? If I understand correctly, while db is executing `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, under the hood the db must verify that row doesn't exists (unique), by finding it. So, id of row can be fetechd (while row is already found) or will be created. If insert of `category` or `region` returned id, this id could be used in inserting `Offers` and `OfferRegions`.

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: Your solution is sufficient for me. So, I make `Category` insert as `WITH cat_id AS (INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('cat1')  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id)` and later i use `cat_id` as `... WHEN (SELECT * FROM cat_id) IS NULL ...`, right? Is there still race condition if, whole statement is between `BEGIN` ... `COMIT`?

Comment: But that will return `id` only if the row was inserted, not if it was already present.